# redirecting clickhouse-client to docker volume mount path

Tags: docker, clickhouse

I'm running clickhouse on a docker container and mounted volumes on an external harddrive:

```bash
sudo docker run --name clickhouse-server \
  --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 \
  -p 18123:8123 \
  -p 19000:9000 \
  -p 19009:9009 \
  -v ./clickhouse:/var/lib/clickhouse \
  -v ./clickhouse-server:/var/log/clickhouse-server \
  -dit clickhouse/clickhouse-server
```

I installed `clickhouse-client` using `apt` and this seems to assume that clickhouse is installed locally.
When I run

```bash
clickhouse-client \
  --port 19000  \
  --input_format_csv_skip_first_lines 1 \
  --date_time_input_format 'best_effort' \
  -q "INSERT INTO mytable FROM INFILE './data/mytable_data1.csv.gz'"
```

This raises the following error:

```bash
DB::Exception: Received from localhost:19000. 
DB::ErrnoException. DB::ErrnoException: Cannot set modification time 
for file: /var/lib/clickhouse/store/18d/18d1dbb9-3d04-4a43-b9f3-8393420d1c8b/tmp_insert_all_3_3_0/, 
errno: 1, strerror: Operation not permitted. (PATH_ACCESS_DENIED)
```

I believe `/var/lib/clickhouse` should be redirected to my docker volume mount path `/media/user/data/clickhouse`.

Simple queries such as `SHOW TABLES` seem to work fine:

```bash
clickhouse-client --port 19000  -q "show tables"
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would exec a shell in the container and check the owner and perms on /var/lib/clickhouse/store and the id of the clickhouse server process.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. You have to use the `-u` option to specify the user ID and group id of the user that owns the mounted directory on the host system.

```bash
docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /media/user/data/clickhouse:/var/lib/clickhouse
```

When you run the docker container, you need to mount the directory with the correct permission. The above command mounts the `/media/user/data/clickhouse` directory on the host system to `/var/lib/clickhouse` inside the container and sets the user ID and group ID of the container to match the owner of the mounted directory on the host system.